# What's with reputation? Why do I need some to comment?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, privileges

I created an account to contribute an to an issue.  Now I see that I can't.

I have no idea what hoops I should be jumping through to contribute, but I don't think there should be any.

I need 50 reputation, whatever that means.  I'm sure that kills a lot of posts.  There are thousands of sites like this one that require you to join to comment.  They all want you to hang out, have coffee, make them your home.  Not.

My brand new Nexus 7 is having random wifi connect issues.  But I can't comment on the thread about it.

Comment: You might want to read this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 6):

As you've noticed, you need more reputation points to comment on someone else's post than to ask or answer a question. Why's that? Because new users don't always understand how this site is different from a web forum or a mailing list. They don't always realise that Stack Exchange sites have *questions* and *answers*, rather than threads and replies. Sometimes, new users think it's appropriate to add a comment to a question to say, "I'm having the same problem too," or to "bump the thread". **That's not how this site works.** Comments like that don't add anything to the site, so we don't want them. If you're having the same problem as someone else, you can *star* the question to be notified of new answers.

I notice that you used the term "thread" in your question. Perhaps you've fallen into the same trap: it's an easy enough misunderstanding to make until you read the FAQ or use the site for a while. That misunderstanding is exactly what the privilege system is for. Once upon a time, it was customary to *lurk* on a mailing list or BBS (that is, to read the site without posting), so that you can learn the conventions and the culture of the site rather than posting in the wrong place. The privilege system exists, in part, to help keep that custom alive here.

It's up to you whether you participate or not. As you say, there are are plenty of web fora out there if that's all you want. But if you stick around, I think you'll find, as I have, that Stack Exchange's reputation and privileges help keep the quality of discourse more productive than you find on the average forum or mailing list.

Comment: I like especially the "lurker's guide". That's exactly how I started at SE and some other fora, even before "subscribing" at all. To be recommended, really.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't take any time to learn anything about the site you're visiting, it's not going to work for you.  [Start here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

We're not *obligated* to help you, and we **are** a community-led site.  Driveby comments that can be left by anyone are not in our best interest.  You will notice that you don't even need to sign up to post a question or answer, however.

Without knowing what question you're referring to or what your comment would be, it's hard to help you further.